# ER Model weak entities.

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

As per these instructions, i am trying to create a ER model. With
 these instructions:

> Total Escapes has a wide variety of tours on offer to its customers. 
>   Each tour can be uniquely identified by a route ID. A tour also has
>   associated with it an estimated duration and a description of the tour
>   itself.
>
> Customer details are to be recorded in the database, with a unique
>   customer ID generated for each customer. Additional details include a
>   name, date of birth and contact phone number. A Tour run is defined as
>   one instance of a tour, i.e. a tour has a number of tour runs. For
>   example, a ‘Melbourne City Tour’ runs twice every day, 8:30am and
>   2:30pm. In other words, a Tour run is identified by not only a
>   specific tour but the date and time that tour was operated.
>
> A customer can book tour runs. The price paid for the booking is
>   recorded. A vehicle is used by a driver to perform his/her duties in
>   taking tourists on a route.  Each vehicle can be identified by it
>   registration plates. Other attributes such as vehicle type, capacity
>   and colour are also recorded.
>
> A Tour guide organizes a tour run in coordination with the driver. The
>   tour guide must have a unique certificate number to be recorded in the
>   system. Their name, mobile number and address are also required. The
>   driver responsible for operating the tour vehicle on a tour run can be
>   identified by their D/L number. A name and mobile phone number are
>   also recorded in the database for each driver.
>
> Some tour guides train other tour guides to manage tours themselves.
>   Each trainee has one supervisor while a supervisor can guide many
>   trainees.

On the diagram that i have created I am wondering if the link between instance and tour would be the many to exactly one?

OR is the tour run not even a weak entity?

[ER Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FFyq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `Tour Run` is a weak entity - the instructions are very specific about this. That means `Instance` is an identifying relationship, mapping `Route_ID` values to `Route_ID,Date,Time` values. This is a trivial relation that wouldn't need to be recorded separately from `Tour Run` keys. You're also correct that the association between `Instance` and `Tour` is many-to-one - many `Route_ID,Date,Time` triplets map to one `Route_ID`.

Comment: Cheers for that, I just needed to ensure i was on the right path!